# NGINX: Download stops after 1GB - upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)

Tags: nginx, php

i have a huge Problem on my site.
Please help me to fix it.

i have a site where users can download files from different other sites (f.e one-click-hoster like uploaded.net). We act as like a proxy. The user generate a link and download the file directly. Our Script download nothing on the server. A little bit like a premium link generator but different. AND NOT ILLEGAL.

If the user are downloading a file that is larger than 1GB, the download will be canceled when it reachs 1gb.

In the log files i found repeated the error
"Upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response"

I have tried to put the settings higher but that didn't help.

I tried following:

```
1. nginx.conf:
   fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
   fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;

2. nginx host file:
   fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
   fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
   fstcgi_buffer_size 256k;

3. PHP.ini:
   max_execution_time = 60 (but my php script will set it automaticly to 0)
   max_input_time = 60
   memory_limit = 128M

4. PHP-FPM >> www.conf
   pm.max_children = 25
   pm.start_servers = 2
   pm.min_spare_servers = 2
   pm.max_spare_servers = 12
   request_terminate_timeout = 300s
```

But nothing helps. What can i do to fix this problem?

```
Server/Nginx Infos:
Memory: 32079MB
CPU: model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 v3 @ 3.30GHz (8 Cores)
PHP: PHP 5.5.15-1~dotdeb.1 (cli) (built: Jul 24 2014 16:44:04)
NGINX: nginx/1.2.1

nginx.conf:
worker_processes  8;
worker_connections  2048;
```

But time settings are doens't matter i think. Because the download stops exactly on 1.604.408 KB everytime. If i download with 20kb/s the download needs more time, but will cancel on exactly 1.604.408 KB.

thank you for any help.
If you need more informations please ask me.

Comment: Please try this with an updated version of Nginx - v1.2.1 is really old.

Comment: Try to raise the value of "fastcgi_connect_timeout", "fastcgi_read_timeout" in nginx.conf.

Comment: i am using the dotdeb packages so i would have to remove nginx and php to install the normal/newer. or can I simply overwrite the packages when I adjust the sources.list?
On what a value i should try the "fastcgi_connect_timeout" ?

Comment: But time settings are doens't matter i think. Because the download stops exactly on 1.604.408 KB everytime. If i download with 20kb/s the download needs more time, but will cancel on exactly 1.604.408 KB.

Comment: Ok, then let's focus on the size settings. give client_max_body_size 2G; or 0; in nginx.conf a try. setting 0 disabled it.

Comment: Tried client_max_body_size with 4G and 0. But doesn't work. Today the download cancels at 1.053.280kb (1028mb)

Comment: This problem has been resolved. For all others with the same Problem:
Our problem was, that the server/script downloaded all things into the temp folder. The default value was 1024mb. we set the value to 16gb by "max_temp_file_size 16G" in the nginx.conf

Comment: Nice catch! But it makes me wonder, if its possible to turn the proxy_buffering off. I mean: why buffer the download content of another server? I don't know if this has an performance impact. I guess, you would only loose the data for progressbar display.

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer and mark as accepted? :)

Comment: in what file to put "max_temp_file_size 16G"?

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem, where download would stop at 1024MB with error

```
readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream
```

adding this to nginx.conf file helped:

```
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 1024m;
```